# jQuery append to dynamicly created child div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamically-generated

I am trying to append text to a div which has been dynamically created. Within this div there are 2 child divs, one for title and one for the body.

This main div is droppable, however I want that when the item is dropped, the text enters into the child div "body".

I currently have the following code which appends the text to the main div.

```
 $($(this)).append(draggableText + '<br>');
```

The name of the child div is **#catPileBoxBody**

However there are 3 of these which have been dynamically created. So is there a way of inserting the text into something like:

```
$($(this."CHILD called #catPileBoxBody")).append(draggableText + '<br>');
```

Any help would be massively appreciated! I have been stumped on this for AGES!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(this).find("#catPileBoxBody").append(draggableText + '<br>');
```

But as you should have only one element with a given ID, you should be able to simply do

```
$("#catPileBoxBody").append(draggableText + '<br>');
```

The fact that the divs have been created dynamically changes nothing.

Comment: Thanks so much! Im only realising now IDs should be unique. I changed it to a class and edited the code to

`var parent =  $(this).find(".catPileBoxBody");
$(parent).append(draggableText + '<br>');`

Answer (score 1):

You can append it in the following manner

**Edited:**

```
   $(this).find('div.yourClass').append(draggableText + '<br>');
```

Comment: Thanks but I needed to make it a class and get it from under the selected element "this"